# VisualForce to PDF - Styling shows on Preview, but Extra Spacing in Rendered PDF

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf

I have applied a CSS sheet to Style a rendered PDF.
All styling appears in the preview.

Here is an example of the preview:
[image]

However, when the PDF is rendered and attached to the related record, the spacing in this section increases dramatically.

[image]

***Here are some things I have already tried:***

- Adding styling via CSS
- Adding styling inline
- Including escape="false"
- Setting all styling to style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;
- Again, the preview of the PDF changes with the adjustments to styling, so the styling is being applied - However, once rendered to a PDF, the styling is lost on the Rich Text Field items, and double-spacing occurs.

***Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?***

Comment: How are you applying the css? Is it inline?

Comment: @DanielHoechst - It is not inline - It's referencing a Static Resource where I uploaded the CSS doc.

Comment: Pretty sure that's your problem. I think you'll need to put all your CSS inline. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004706

Comment: Unfortunately, putting CSS inline did not have an effect on the rendered PDF.  The preview of the PDF updated, as expected.  However, the actual PDF still had the issue with spacing.